# Generating vector slope maps using GDAL

Tags: gdal, dem, slope, gdal-contour, gdaldem

I have a DEM file that I created a slope map of using `gdaldem slope`. This works fine and if I view and colorize it, I can now see how steep a hill is but now I'd love to create a shapefile out of that. So I'd like to have polygons with increments of let's say 5% for each level of steepness.

I though I would go ahead and create `gdal_contour` of that slope-DEM file and using the `-p` option to create polygons rather than lines, but the problem is, that this takes FOREVER. Even a small sample file of a few square-kilometers (and about 20MB in file-size) is taking a couple of hours.

My command was: `gdal_contour -i 5 -amin 30 -p input.tif output.shp` So increments of 5% starting at 30% and polygons.

How can I approach my problem?

**Additional Info:**
For @gabriels anwser. Here's what that looks. So you can basically see each "pixel".
[image]

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: I just removed the second question! thx

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that contour lines may not be closed, so it's hard to create the polygons.

Simplest GDAL way seems to me classify the raster and then polygonize it.

`gdal_calc.py  --calc='(A<=30)*30+(A>30)*A//5*5' --outfile=classified.tif -A input.tif`

The calc expression turns all values less than 30 to 30, and greater values are rounded to the floor mutiplier of 5. Then, polygonize the classified raster:

`gdal_polygonize.py classified.tif output.shp`

Comment: That looks pretty promising!!! Thank you! One question. The result has no "aliasing" (not sure about the correct word). It looks very edgy... I'll update my question and add a screenshot so you can see what I mean. Is there any way around that?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it's the price we pay to obtain all valid geometries. You can subsample the source image with a bilinear method to get some interpolation before the classification. Here a non pure GDAL alternative: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350386/133276.

Comment: Ok I see... So there is no other way to do that efficiently? Cause even when upscaling the image, in the end it will still always be "rectangular" shapes, right?

Comment: Polygonize the raster is always rectangular. Smooth are contour lines, but you must create closed lines to polygonize them.

Comment: Ok, but the `-p` for `gdal_contour` should do that, right? But just very slow?!?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm seeing that is not only closed linestring the problem, also detecting islands and other things. But I think that must be a way to automatize the process with gdal, but without the `-p` option.